# Passing Variables to a MongoDB View

Tags: mongodb

i'm trying to make views in MongoDB to avoid unnecessary returns. In the documentation says that the aggregation functions can take variables with a double dollar sign, taking this in mind i have created a view that in this example should take one variable to filter customerIds and group the results to sum the payments of different documents.

Example:

```
db.createView(
  "viewName",
  "myCollection",
  [{
    $match: {  "customerId": "$$customerId", }
  },{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: "$amount",
    }
  }]
)
```

The view is created OK and if i put some valid customerId in the aggregation function that works ok, but i don't have the slightest idea how to execute the view and pass the `customerID` that i need.

Any ideas? The mongodb documentation does not help me in this situation and i really need to create this as a view, since there are many applications that will connect to this view(s).

I have tried:
    db.viewName.find({customerId: "some valid id"});

Comment: It would be great to hear if you figured this out. I'm looking at the `AggregateOptions` which include the ability to set a `let` value with a variable. However, I'm creating my view through Compass so I get var not found. Tomorrow I will try creating the view programmatically and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

You can access it just like a collection, for example I am creating a view via:

```
db.runCommand({
  create: 'AuthorsView',
  viewOn: 'authors',
  pipeline: [{
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$email",
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }]
})
```

Since this is now an existing view I can simply do:

```
db.getCollection('AuthorsView').find({})
```

To see all the documents or to add more parameters to the `find`

Not sure what you mean by passing variables since views are just like collections ... you run queries against them via `find` & `aggregate`.

Comment: The thing here is that the filter method acts after the aggregation pipeline. And by passing variables, i want the view to receive for example, a company id to only calculate the amounts for that company. for example:

`db.myView({companyId: 'somevalidid'})`

Comment: Was there ever a solution found to this? It’s exactly what I’m looking for. I have a view that starts with a $match that restricts the data sent into the rest of the pipeline, but i need to pass in a value to the $match.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't pass variables to `$match` without `$expr`. There is no error because "$$..." is interpreted as a string.

Second, If we fix things like this:

```
db.createView(
  "viewName",
  "myCollection",
  [{
    $match: {$expr:{$eq:["$customerId","$$customerId"]}}, }
  },{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: "$amount",
    }
  }]
)
```

But `$$` is not a system variable, so this won't work. You could pass a system variable like `$$ROOT` or a field path `$field.path`; the **user-defined** variables are made up of system variables or collection data.